# Where can I find .cargo/config?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I don't have this file in `c:/user/me/.cargo/`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As described in [the Cargo documentation](http://doc.crates.io/config.html), there's no *one* place for `.cargo`:

> Cargo allows local configuration for a particular project as well as
>   global configuration, like git. Cargo extends this to a hierarchical
>   strategy. If, for example, Cargo were invoked in
>   `/projects/foo/bar/baz`, then the following configuration files would
>   be probed for and unified in this order:
>
> - `/projects/foo/bar/baz/.cargo/config`
> - `/projects/foo/bar/.cargo/config`
> - `/projects/foo/.cargo/config`
> - `/projects/.cargo/config`
> - `/.cargo/config`
> - `$HOME/.cargo/config`

The [complete algorithm](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/0.21.1/src/cargo/util/config.rs#L809-L835) also searches in your home directory.

**You** are supposed to create the directory in whichever place is most appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Given the context it might be useful to note that Cargo *should* be searching `%USERPROFILE%\.cargo`, since that's not necessarily a parent directory.  The Cargo documentation you linked doesn't appear to touch on where it searches on Windows at all.

Comment: @DK. Or I could update the original docs to be clearer about always checking `$HOME` ^_^.

Comment: Except it's not *called* `$HOME` on Windows, it's called `%USERPROFILE%` (unless you're using an environment that *fakes* a `HOME` variable, which is not universally true).  Hence why I specifically noted the OS.

Comment: @DK. Or *you* could update the original docs to be clearer that `$HOME` and `%USERPROFILE%` are interchangeable here ^_^.