# Can I make Cargo ignore .cargo/config in enclosing directories?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The default behavior is for Cargo to [search for `.cargo/config` files all the way to the root of the system](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html).

Is there some way that I can define a boundary for the probe?  For example,  I don't want a lower-level directory to use vendored source that the encapsulating project wants to use. Instead, I want the lower-level invocation to use the default for `[source.crates-io]`.

See also:

- [Where can I find .cargo/config?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46649992/155423)

Comment: I don't think there is a way, but I wish there were. I ran into issues with Rust in Buildroot, because it found the linker config in my home directory before the project-specific one.