# Where does the custom Cargo command "install-ra" in rust-analyzer come from?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The instructions to build [rust-analyzer](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer) say to run this command:

```
cargo install-ra
```

It works, but how? It's not an official command and it isn't in `cargo --list` or `Cargo.toml`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The repository in question contains a custom **local Cargo configuration file** in [".cargo/config"](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/blob/master/.cargo/config). In this case, it defines a bunch of aliases, including `install-ra`:

```
[alias]

# Installs the visual studio code extension
install-ra   = "run --package ra_tools --bin ra_tools -- install-ra"
install-code = "run --package ra_tools --bin ra_tools -- install-ra" # just an alias
```

See also:

- [Where can I find .cargo/config?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46649992/1233251)